# Оставить в мемо только первые 32 символа, а всё остальное удалить

Tags: delphi

Допустим, что в мемо есть какой-то текст. Как оставить в мемо только **первые** 32 символа, а всё остальное удалить?

Answer (score 1):

```
Memo1.Text := copy(Memo1.Text, 0, 32);
```

как то так, но не помню какого типа Memo1.Text, возможно нужно будет преобразовать в PСhar

Answer (score 1):

Если не учитывать знаки переноса и разбивку по строкам, то так:

```
Memo1.Text := Copy(Memo1.Text, 1, 32);
```